# Single executable for React App and Express API

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, npm

I have a React App and a Express API. I want to package those two components into one single executable. Is there a way to do this? I don’t want a solution to my problem I want a hint into the right direction if this is possible.

Comment: Here's one way I put together: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you mean is not to keep the bundler running as well as the express server, unfortunately that's not possible if you're in developer mode (and) you're expecting realtime updates in your browser, but if you were in production, then it's not even the case that you need to run your bundler, cause your `main.bundle.js` is already built and ready.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. https://electronjs.org/

Electron or similar libraries help you to create an executable application which can be installed an run like a desktop application.

The only point you have to keep in mind is for accessing the database you will have to create a REST API and communicate via that.

[Link for a simple tutorial.](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app)